# Issue while publishing the Enterprise Bot Template (SDK V4+C# ) from Visual Studio 2017 to azure app services

Tags: azure, c#-4.0, botframework, chatbot, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I am writing on behalf of my Friend  "Tharak".

Faced an issue while publishing the Enterprise Bot Template (SDK V4,C#.net ) from Visual Studio 2017 IDE. Refer the error screen shot after deployed to Azure app-service. Even I tried by placing /api/messages at the end of the URL. While publishing the solution from Visual studio, getting published success

[attached error pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ysnv.jpg)

It can be helpful if anyone share the guidelines/articles on Deployment of Enterprise Bot Template (Especially SDK V4,C#.net). Is there any difference on deployment from sdk-v3 to sdk-v4?
since SDK V3 can able to deploy/browse the application successfully

I also updated the App ID, App Password in .Bot file as well as in App Service(From Azure Portal).

Tried with updating the Nuget Package version from 4.2.0 to 4.2.2 and .Net Framework version 2.1 to 2.2(asp.net-core)

Please help

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your deployment went sideways.

Deploying a Enterprise bot is no different from deploying any other v4 bot. The BF team recommends following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-deploy-az-cli?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) to deploy, but there is actually a second way:

If you right click your sln file and select 'Publish', you can publish your bot as a web app service (NOT A BOT SERVICE). Then, once it's deployed, you can go into Azure and create a 'bot channels registration' resource in the same resource group as the web app service you just deployed.

You would have to make the AppId and AppPassword manually, following these steps:

1. While creating your Bot Channels Registration, choose the same Subscription where you deployed your bot’s code.
2. Pick your existing Resource group which will set the location (THIS MUST MATCH WEB APP SERVICE).
3. You can choose the F0 Pricing tier for development and testing.
4. Enter your bot’s URL. Make sure you start with HTTPS and that you add the /api/messages For examplehttps://yourbotname.azurewebsites.net/api/messages
5. Turn off Application Insights for now.
6. Click the Microsoft App ID and password
7. In the new blade click Create New.
8. In the new blade that opens to the right, click the "Create App ID in the App Registration Portal" which will open in a new browser tab.
9. In the new tab, make a copy of the App ID and save it somewhere.
10. Click the Generate an app password to continue button.
11. A browser dialog opens and provides you with your app’s password, which will be the only time you get it. Copy and save this password somewhere you can get to later.
12. Click OK once you’ve got the password saved.
13. Just close the browser tab and return to the Azure Portal tab.
14. Paste in your App ID and Password in the correct fields and click OK.
15. Now click Create to set up your channel registration. This can take a few seconds to a few minutes.

Once you've done this, take the AppID and AppPassword from steps 9 and 11, and add them to the settings tab of the 'web app service' (the bot logic):

[image]